# Poor quality font when connecting MBP 2016 to external 27 inch full HD monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have bought a [Samsung 27" Full HD (LC27R500FHNXZA)](https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/samsung-27-fhd-60hz-4ms-gtg-curved-va-led-monitor-lc27r500fhnxza-dark-blue-grey/13730025) monitor and have connected my MacBook Pro 2016 (macOS 10.13 "High Sierra") to it via HDMI.

This is the image I see:
[image]

And this is the image I see on my own display:
[image]

I still see individual pixels clearly. I tried to follow [this guide](https://gist.github.com/adaugherity/7435890) to copy the generated file in the `Overrides` folder and restarted my MacBook Pro, but it didn't work.  Any idea?

Maybe full hd is too small a resolution for a 27 inch monitor?

Comment: Yup, "full HD"[1920x1080] is icons like dinner plates on a 27" monitor. I'd call 1440p [2560 x 1440] about right for a non-HiDPI 27" screen.

Answer (score 2):

The quality of the image is dependent (among other things) on the density of the pixels -- how small they are.

A 27" display of 1920 x 1080 pixels will have a pixel density of around 82 pixels per inch.

To give some perspective, your MacBook Pro's display has a pixel density of 219 pixels per inch. The very first iPhone had a density twice that of your screen.

When buying a monitor, it's not just how big it is, but how many pixels it has. The Apple Thunderbolt Display, for example, is 27" but with 2560 x 1440 pixels, so 109dpi. There are plenty of  27" displays with 3840 x 2160 pixels ("4K"), so c. 164 ppi.

The higher the pixel density, the sharper the image and text. You can't really expect great quality from a 1080p 27" display.

Note that some manufacturers specify 'pixel pitch' rather than PPI. Pitch is the size of one pixel, so 109ppi is 0.233mm pitch; 219ppi is 0.116mm.